# Continuously running laravel-echo-server with Supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-echo

I have installed & configured Supervisor & Laravel-Echo-Server and i have set up a program that is supposed to continuously run a laravel-echo-server and it looks like this:

```
[program:laravel-echo-server]
directory=/var/www/html/laravel
command=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
user=root
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laravel-echo-server.log
```

The command line error i'm getting is: `laravel-echo-server: ERROR (spawn error)`

The error in the log file is: `/usr/bin/env:  ^^xnode ^^y: No such file or directory`

What i've tried so far is:

Checked if laravel-echo-server is installed globally with `npm list -g laravel-echo-server` (it is).

Defined absolute path to the laravel-echo-server that looks like this:
`command=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir /var/www/html/laravel`

Created a sym link for the laravel-echo-server in `usr/bin`, and i placed
 `laravel-echo-server.json` files both in the sym link & in the absolute path (for testing purposes, to see if i can start the server from there - I can), again redefined the command in the program to `command=laravel-echo-server start`, nothing works and i'm out of ideas.

Can someone help me out with what i'm doing wrong?

P.S. Again for testing purposes, i've set up PM2 and when i run the `laravel-server-echo` thru it it says that it's online but it's really not, so i'm assuming that it probably encounters similar error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem: 
`ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node`

From what i understand, this is bug for Node on Debian.